# Fast OS/filesystems/utilities to work with very large numbers of files

Tags: filesystems

I work (create, read, copy, delete, count the number of) with millions of files under Windows XP (and NTFS). Are there any other filesystems or OS better optimized for dealing with millions of files? Can you provide any suggestions on how I can significantly speed up things (say, copy/delete/count)? Any useful utilities?

Comment: Millions of files in a directory will kill pretty much *any* OS and/or filesystem.

Comment: So maybe the approach should be to store data in fewer files?

Comment: Or to use a hierarchy of folders to partition the files.

Answer (score 1):

I use FAR Manager when dealing with large numbers of files.  It's ideally suited for this sort of task because you can set up filters to limit the number of files you see at one time:

FAR Manager (free and open source)
  http://www.farmanager.com/

Both 32-bit and 64-bit editions are available, which is particularly important when dealing with really large numbers of files since 64-bit processing will yield a definite advantage for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check [DiskBoss](http://www.diskboss.com).

> DiskBoss is an automated, rule-based
>   file and disk management solution
>   allowing one to perform disk space
>   utilization analysis, file
>   classification and categorization,
>   duplicate files detection and removal,
>   high-speed file synchronization and
>   data migration, disk change
>   monitoring, rule-based file
>   organizing, data wiping and much more.

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds a design issue. You should
   revise your solution.
2. Format your drive(s) with a lower
   cluster size to save some space.
3. [`Total commander`](http://www.ghisler.com/) is a good
   utility for this purpose. Maybe you
   need to develop your own
   `business-oriented` solution.

Comment: Regarding 1: I work with raw files produced in hundreds of thousands by mass spectrometers analyzing protein samples and with results of protein identification in these files. Maybe I should write to the major producers of mass spectrometers and to the developers of protein identification software that they should revise their solutions.

Comment: Odds are good that these software developers are interested in their customers feedback, and if you are paying for support, then this type of request should absolutely be submitted to them.

Comment: @Leo: So small data is not suitable to be written on file system. A database is more suitable here.